# Break multiple values from lines

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a select that gives me a result like:

```
A, B, C
C, D, E
G, A
NULL
O, U, B, X
```

I would like to have the result like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
G
O
U
X
```

So, instead of multiple values from lines, each value should be in 1 line with `DISTINCT` and without `NULL`

Tried to use SQLFIDDLE to create an example but it is not working.

Comment: use `SqlFiddle` to create the DDL, but use [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) to test the query.

Comment: those row are 4 fields `'O', 'U', 'B', 'X'` or is a single string `'O, U, B, X'`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, It is a single string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone should have a good split/parse function.

**Option 1 without a UDF**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('A, B, C'),
('C, D, E'),
('G, A'),
(NULL),
('O, U, B, X')

Select Distinct B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where B.RetVal is not null
```

**Option 2 With a Parse/Spit UDF**

```
Select Distinct B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.SomeCol,',') B
 Where B.RetVal is not null
```

**Both Return**

```
RetVal
A
B
C
D
E
G
O
U
X
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: Tried to use the Option 2, but couldn't figure out the part `[dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]`. What should I use here? Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys Option 2 requires the UDF

Comment: @Khrys I understand some OPs may not create UDFs as a matter of policy that is why I supplied two options.  The first is stand-alone

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Never had a doubt  :)

Comment: Thanks. First one worked great. Thanks for the time from all you guys.

Comment: @Khrys Happy to help  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross apply` to unpivot them.  The rest is just `select distinct`:

```
select distinct v.val
from t cross apply
     (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) val
where val is not null;
```

Comment: what are `col1, col2, col3` here?

Comment: I am trying to use this without success. I have only one column with the values. Thanks for any more info.